# dynamic mariadb update query using node.js

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I'm new to node.js and I am trying to make simple CRUD operations using mysql dependency.

everything seems fine, but I find a problem when i try to build update function.

I have a sample table with 3 columns in my database: uid(int) as primary key, id(string) as unique key, and data(int).

in case of update i have to check the values which column should be updated one by one and make different query every case(in this demo 3 cases=3 queries required)

i'm ok with this simple demo but in real work it will be a huge pain if multiple column is exists in my table. (in case of n columns i need (2^n)-1 queries!)

is there any good tools to use make it automatically?

i tried to make queries manually but obviously this is bad solution of this...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why do you need a `uid` if `id` is unique? Databases are capable of more than just CRUD. Why do "values which column should be updated one by one"? I don't think you should be writing a generic database wrapper. Write the functions of the business logic. Ref [MariaDB Connector/JS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-the-nodejs-connector/). I don't see how making queries manually is a bad solution.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I just assume that id can be changed but even that situation there must be an unchanged valued is needed. (actually it is a demo and the constraints are not necessary except for pk) my pseudocode for update logic is below: 
`function update(object) { if(object contains id) { if(object contains data) { query(update with id, data) } else { query(update with id only) } } else { query(update with data only) } }` so.. is this really only solution? is there nothing like dynamic query modification with if(condition) clause(such as mybatis <if>tags)

Comment: If you want an orm, maybe [sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) or [prisma](https://github.com/prisma/prisma). If you are coding in JS database things it will be subject to race conditions with other threads. I'm not seeing a tangible problem solved by your pseudocode. Hope someone else does.

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself. i make a new function for make query dynamically.
here is pseudocode:

```js
function queryMake(object) {
  let dataArray = [], query = "1=1 "
  if(object has id) { query += "and id=?"; dataArray.push(object.id); }
  if(object has data) { query += "and data=?"; dataArray.push(object.data); }
  return {
    query: query,
    dataArray: dtaArray
  }
}
```

and send it to mysql connection query.